# How to skip labels on x-axes?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image: Chart]

I've been trying for a long time now to figure out how to skip labels on the x-axes of this chart. So, for instance, display every third or fourth label. I've tried adding autoSkip and stepSize to the tick-configuration, but nothing changes. Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit:

```
visitorsLabels = ["januar", "desember", "november", "oktober", "september", "august", "juli", "juni", "mai", "april", "mars", "februar"]

var visitors_data = [2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1];

var ctx1 = $("#chart-visitors"); 

var graph_visitors_preset = {
    labels: visitorsLabels,
    datasets: [
        {
            fill: true,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "#f9f9f9",
            borderColor: "#72bce3",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: visitors_data,
            spanGaps: true,
        }
    ]
};
var chart_visitors = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: 'line',
    data: graph_visitors_preset,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: { display: false },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{

                ticks: {autoSkip: true, stepSize: 3, max: 5, min: 2},
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{

                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Would help if you included the code for your chart :)

Comment: I appreciate it. Code added :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the chart options, you can change an axe's ticks' callback to display the tick (the label) based on a value, or even change what it displays :

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                callback: function(tick, index, array) {
                    return (index % 3) ? "" : tick;
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

This option basically display one tick every three.

---

You can check a full script in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9jst5ar/1/), and here is its result :

[image]

Comment: This was a very neat way of doing it. I didn't know it was that simple. Thank you!

Comment: I know I've already marked this as solved, but I have a very relevant question. Why is it impossible to view two equal labels on the x axes without them overlapping and destroying the chart. If, for instance, I continue the chart with all the months of two years (so that each month is displayed twice on the chart), half of the the labels go bold and half of them disappear at the end. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @Pelle Hmm I've never seen this kind of bug, and [couldn't reproduce it](https://jsfiddle.net/q9jst5ar/2/). Could you reproduce it in a fiddle ? So that I can check what's wrong and try to get a fix

Comment: This is strange. I'm not able to reproduce it in a fiddle either, but I took a screen shot of how it looks like here: 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XRmdSl6WwLMmVKOGtFS1NjN00/view?usp=sharing)

This is the fiddle which looks correct: https://jsfiddle.net/4bfr931m/1/ I don't know why it's different.

Comment: @Pelle May be a typo or something, check your code and make sure you have the same thing as your fiddle. Try replacing it with what's in your fiddle, changing what's needed (*maybe you get data from elsewhere I don't know*) and then checking if it's good -- From what I have here, I cannot help you further

Comment: No typos. I was using an older version of ChartJS (2.2.1 I believe) and when I switched to the same version used in the fiddle you posted, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: @Pelle Glad you found the issue

Answer (score 0):

In chart.js version 4 you have to call `this.getLabelForValue` method to get the original label for the tick

```
scales: {
  x: {
    ticks: {
      // For a category axis, the val is the index so the lookup via getLabelForValue is needed
      callback: function(val, index) {
        // Hide every 3rd tick label
        return index % 3 === 0 ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
      },
      color: 'red',
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example from Chart.js website: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html