# How to skip x Axes labels in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

The only thing I found for this topic is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41760855/how-to-skip-labels-on-x-axes)
, but it does not really help solve the problem.

So I have a chart which is filled with some data like this:
[image: ChartJS Example]

As you can see the values which are not set in the dataSet, are cut off. This is because of this code which fills everything with `undefined`:

```
let dataSet: any = {
   label: user.userName,
   backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
   borderColor: this.getRandomColor(),
   data: new Array(this.chart.data.labels.length).fill(undefined)
}
```

After that I fill the data in with this code:

```
data.forEach((d)=>{
   let tmpDate: Date = new Date(d.date * 1000)
   let insertIndex: number = this.chart.data.labels.indexOf(this.getDateString(tmpDate))
   dataSet.data.splice(insertIndex, 1, d.data) // d.data is a number
})

this.chart.data.datasets.push(dataSet)
this.chart.update()
```

I would like it to skip the undefined values and create a smooth line across the chart.

Comment: If the undefineds are the issue, you can use filter function to remove them. `dataSet = dataSet.filter(function(el) { return el; });`

Comment: @Bryan They are not the issue. Without them, the real data wouldn't get to the xAxes point where it is supposed to be. It would just get added one after the other (but the data needs to be at the right date).

Comment: Well if you want a smooth line and each date needs a value, maybe you can fill undefined items with the previous or next value or an average of them ((next + prev) / 2)?

Comment: yeah that is my workaround for now. but this is still not really pretty. It would look alot better if it would just connect all real values. Thanks for the effort tho @Bryan

Comment: Found something that might be what you're looking for. `spanGaps` option: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#configuration-options

Comment: Works like a charm! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it please? @Bryan

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spanGaps` option in the [docs](https://chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#configuration-options) should be what you're looking for.